# Parsing XML namespaces URI as attributes in Poco DOM C++

Tags: c++, xml, soap, poco-libraries

I'm trying to parse namespace URI attributes from the Envelope root tag of SOAP message using Poco c++. I am using a DOMParser to read it.
I am using the following method to parse the attributes. However, the function is not returning any attributes.

```
Poco::XML::NamedNodeMap * nnm = pDoc->documentElement()->attributes();
std::cout << "Node Name:" << pDoc->documentElement()->nodeName() <<std::endl;
std::cout << "NNS size : " << nnm->length() << std::endl;
```

Result of running the above code

```
Node Name: Envelope
NNS size : 0
```

**Why can't the Dom parser parse the namespace URIs as attributes? is it possible to parse them?**

Below is the SOAP message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"
    xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl"
    xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"
    xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
    <s:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>uuid:6cd92809-5887-7b13-0ae9-290514f24b6f</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>78e87394-8ba6-41a7-a4c9-8769306a8a0b</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ProbeMatches</wsa:Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <d:ProbeMatches>
            <d:ProbeMatch>
                <wsa:EndpointReference>
                    <wsa:Address>urn:uuid:229c62c6-0903-246d-05bd-7193031a5f5c</wsa:Address>
                </wsa:EndpointReference>
                <d:Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter tds:Device</d:Types>
                <d:Scopes>onvif://www.onvif.org/location/country/china onvif://www.onvif.org/type/video_encoder onvif://www.onvif.org/name/IP-Camera onvif://www.onvif.org/hardware/HI3518C onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/Streaming onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/T onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/G onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/C onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/A</d:Scopes>
                <d:XAddrs>http://192.168.1.160:8000/onvif/device_service</d:XAddrs>
                <d:MetadataVersion>1</d:MetadataVersion>
            </d:ProbeMatch>
        </d:ProbeMatches>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not 'attributes'. They are namespace declarations. A namespace declaration is a part of the XML standard, like the angle brackets and quotes. That's why it does not appear in the DOM.

I strongly suggest that you take a couple of online tutorials on XML/XSD/SOAP before trying anything else. After that, come back and edit your question. Tell us what you are actually trying to do - we can probably help better if we know what the real objective is.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference between an attribute and a namespace declaration. I am trying to parse the SOAP message which is part of WS-Discovery implementation. The <d:Types> tag has two types inside it, with each different namespace prefix. Using Poco you can get the namespace URI given the element using the DOM parser. By you cannot parse the namespace URI given a string prefix. Since Poco doesn't; have a getNamespaces() method; what is the right way to convert the text namespace prefix into the corresponding namespace URI?The purpose of parsing them is to give them to the user

Comment: I suggest that you look more carefully. I've briefly scanned the Poco documentation. Based on first impressions, I would be _very_ surprised if namespaces are not supported. In case it helps, the namespace will be present on every element/attribute, so that's where you should be looking for the getNamespace() accessor function.